# Check if value is between pair of values in a tuple?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, tuples

Is there an efficient way (nice syntax) to check if a value is between two values contained in a tuple?

The best thing I could come up with is:

```
t = (1, 2)
val = 1.5
if t[0] <= val <= t[1]:
    # do something
```

Is there a nicer way to write the conditional?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the chained conditionals? The only improvement I can offer is tuple unpacking for the bounds first: `low, high = t` then `if low <= val <= high:`..

Comment: Nothing, I was wondering if there was syntax sugar to check if a value is between two other values in a tuple.

Comment: No, you already hit upon the syntax here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no dedicated syntax, using chained comparisons is the right way to do this already.

The one 'nicety' I can offer is to use tuple unpacking first, but that's just readability icing here:

```
low, high = t
if low <= val <= high:
```

If you are using a tuple subclass produced by [`collection.namedtuple()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) you could of course also use the attributes here:

```
from collections import namedtuple

range_tuple = namedtuple('range_tuple', 'low high')
t = range_tuple(1, 2)

if t.low <= val <= t.high:
```

Comment: This is a nice little Pythonic thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

You could make your own sugar:

```
class MyTuple(tuple):

    def between(self, other):
        # returns True if other is between the values of tuple 
        # regardless of order
        return min(self) < other < max(self)

        # or if you want False for MyTuple([2,1]).between(1.5)
        # return self[0] < other < self[1]

mt=MyTuple([1,2])    
print mt.between(1.5)
# True
```

Comment: This is a clever idea,  but wouldn't it be better implemented by decorating?

Comment: -1: creating a class for this simple programming problem. Take a lot of memory and CPU overhead.

Comment: @MaximeLorant: That seems a little harsh. All this does is subclass an existing class `tuple` and add the function he asked if existed. Isn't it up to the OP if his needs are worth a subclassing an existing class? Aren't many things in Python simple because there are classes?

Comment: @dawg I found Martijn answer more cleaner in fact (as always). It's true it is subclass of an existing classes, but it's heavier (in term of readability) than just unpack 2 elements of create a namedtuple... For some more complex operation, create a class can be justified however, I agree :-)

Comment: @MaximeLorant: Thats fine, Martin's answer is great. I upvoted it. But -1 for this answer and your comment is a little harsh. It is useful to add the syntax you want to an Python class by subclassing it. It is up to the OP.

Comment: @dawg I would like to remove my "-1" after thoughts indeed, but you need to edit your post (my vote is locked)

Comment: Rather than using a method `between()`, I'd override `__contains()__` so you could do `if x in MyTuple([1,2])` etc. Of course you would no longer want to call it `tuple` of any kind as that implies certain semantics to `in` that no longer apply.

Comment: If the values are always int, could you use `if x in range(*[1,2])`